# Weird IE6/IE layout bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, quirks-mode, strict-mode

I've had quite a few problems with IE6 and our website.

http://www.sweetlets.com/w/solutions/click-stream/features/

At the very top the teaser boxes have scrollbars in IE6, but not IE7, IE8, FF or Chrome. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Same effect in the footer with the 3 boxes in one row. Also scrollbars. Mathematically all fits into the row of 960px. I added up paddings, margins, borders and width and even kept some pixels left...

I simply don't know what is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: (IE6 is now obsolete. If you possibly can, simply forget about supporting this browser.)

Comment: What do you mean by "teaser boxes"? Do you mean the 6 squares on the top... "Usage Statistics", "Performance", etc...? Also, try applying `"overflow: hidden;` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Yes. The six small boxes at the top. And no, we can't forget about IE6. It still makes more than 15% of our users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it'll fix it but I'd put a `clear: both` on `#cf_content` and remove overflow on the following:

```
#main
#content
#cf_content
#cf_content_teaser
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `overflow:hidden;` on the `#cf_content_teaser` to get rid of the scrollbars. Dunno if it's worth investigating further if that resolves the issue. You can apply the same to whatever other div it's happening on.